# How to recover SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, recovery, data-recovery

Is it possible to recover an SQL database if its associated files have been permanently deleted by mistake?

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8h0p.jpg)

Comment: Have you also deleted the transaction log files?  Any database backups to work from?

Comment: It seems there is no transaction log file present. When I right-click on the database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Express, Tasks -> Restore is grayed out.

Comment: First time i ever saw a literal version of "screenshot".

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the database using:

- full database backup stored somewhere your admin chose to be stored
- a tape backup you don't know even exists, but your datacenter admin knows
- a database mirror (you have to break the mirror first)
- a database backup (copyonly?) your developer has somewhere as the base for his dev work
- an old version SQL Server you have just migrated from
- parts of the database hashed all over the xml files your developers store somewhere on their PCs
- ...

Comment: You forgot: Really good memory. Waking up from the nightmare in which the DB was deleted in the first place. A time machine.